# CodeIgniter not submitting/validating

Tags: php, codeigniter

My login form was working before but I noticed today it's not working anymore. I don't understand why. I'm freaking out. I tried lots of things and kinda narrowed it down to the validation. With this code I should be seeing "its good!" after pressing the submit button but it stays on the "Invalid" and the var_dump() always displays false. On the login form I have a username and password field and a submit button with name="submit". The form does submit to the correct controller (login).

```
public function login()
    {
        var_dump($this->input->post());

        if(!$this->input->post('submit'))
        {
            echo 'invalid';
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('login');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'its good!';
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown, therefore the error must lie somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about doing a var_dump() or print_r() of $_POST?
If $_POST is empty, have a look at your view and make sure you haven't set your forms 'method' attribute to 'get'. It should be set to 'post'.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) returns an empty array. It is post and the path is good.

login view:
`code
    <?= form_open('login'); ?>
     <fieldset>
      <p>
       <label>Forum Username:</label>
       <input type="text" name="username" class="<?= form_error('username'); ?>" value="<?= set_value('username'); ?>" />
      </p>
      <p>
       <label>Forum Password:</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" class="<?= form_error('password'); ?>" />
      </p>
      
      <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></p>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
`

Comment: So strange...can you also paste the output of `var_dump(ini_get('variables_order'));` and `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: init_get does not work

Too many characters to post result of var_dump($_REQUEST); I didn't see anything about username and password.

Comment: That's `ini_get()` not `init_get()`

Comment: output of init_get() is string(5) "EGPCS"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.
Your best bet is [enable profiling](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) and debug this.

In your original post, you said you narrowed it down to validation, but even your $_POST is empty so something's going wrong in between you submitting the form and the controller/router bringing you to the login() method.

It could very well be a server side change. You said this stopped working suddenly. If you are running this on a remote host, it might be worth asking your host if they made any changes to their PHP installation.

Comment: I'll try tonight on my local webserver. To my knowledge, it worked 2 days ago locally.

Comment: I just test a basic form and outputted the post data and it works. So it has to be something with the controller.

Comment: It seems like my multilingual addon has been causing the problem. It's been installed since the beginning. It was submitting to /login instead of /en/login. I just put the current url variable in the action. Works now!

Comment: Glad you posted back with the solution. I was really confused as to why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your controller is not getting the data you're expecting.  Double check that the form you're using to submit the data is correct.  You can also use Chrome's Developer Tools or Firebug in Firefox to see what is actually being sent (check under the 'Network' tab and look for the POST or GET request that submits the data).  Chances are you are not sending what you expect for the 'submit' field.